# copy code from one file to other file in c#

Tags: .net, class, clipboard

Using Below Code, We Can Copy Code from One textbox to other textbox.

```
 private void Copybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(txtSour.Text);
        }
        //paste the text
        private void Pastebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDestinatio.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        }
```

My Requirement is:
Copy Code from one file to other file using C#?
Is It possible using ClipBoard? 
Then i need to copy code from one file to other?

Please AnyOne Help me

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Found the answer, Executed Successfully..
Code is `DataObject objData = new DataObject();
            var copyFrom = File.ReadAllText("C:/Get.cs");
            objData.SetText(copyFrom);

            File.AppendAllText("C:/To.cs", objData.GetText());`